# How should I clean this data retrived from the twitter API?

Tags: python, csv, twitter, unicode, tweepy

This script I have retrives tweets from the Twitter API and saves them into a csv file. Currently, the issue is that the tweets to print out fully in the csv file and there are bits of text where whitespaces are still included as well as text such as '\xe2\x80\x99' in the middle of some tweets where there should be punctuation. I tried the following:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search_words,lang="en",since=date_since, tweet_mode = "extended").items(200):
    tweet = tweet.strip()
```

But got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Is also tried adding the line:

if tweet.find('\xe') : continue

And got this:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape
```

Here is my full code:

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


search_words = "gender -filter:retweets"
date_since = "2021-01-28"


#tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search_words, lang="en",since=date_since).items(100)

# open and create a file to append the data to
csvFile = open('results.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
# use the csv file
# loop through the tweets variable and add them to the CSV file
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search_words,lang="en",since=date_since, tweet_mode = "extended").items(200):
    tweet.strip()
    if tweet.find('\xe') : continue
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
    print(tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
csvFile.close()
```

Try running this code and looking at the csv file to see the problem I have yourself. Please let me know how I should clean these tweets.

Comment: As I understand it, you get the object `tweet` and try to `strip` the object, not a string.

Comment: If you are getting python class then try to print `tweet.__dict__` and see which attribute contains the tweet text. Next, work with the string attribute, not with the object.

Comment: see `print( type(tweet) )` - if it is not `str` then you can't use `strip()`.

Comment: you can do only `tweet.full_text.strip()` but it makes no sense if you don't assign it to varaible - ie. `text = tweet.full_text.strip()` and later use `text`.